# Is it possible to use the script functions i have written via the web published sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet to log trips and miles for work. I have a separate page that has 4 buttons to make the logging easier for the team (start, arrive, delivered, arrive home).
I would like to have a web published version so the team can access it while on the road, unfortunately, the Script within the buttons won't work on this version.
I have tried embedding the page in Google Site but the script is still not active. I have also checked other sites for advice but i can't find anyone who has asked/answered this question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Good question include a brief description of the search/research efforts made, so please edit your question to share them. Ref. [ask].

Comment: I have a spreadsheet to log trips and miles for work. I have a separate page that has 4 buttons to make the logging easier for the team (start, arrive, delivered, arrive home). I would like to have a web published version so the team can access it while on the road, unfortunately, the Script within the buttons won't work on this version.

Comment: All the important details should be included on the question so, please edit it. By the other hand your comment doesn't mention anything related to your search/research efforts about the feature that you are looking for. Have you read the documentation? Does it mention anything about using scripts on spreadsheets published as web pages? Have you considered to embed your spreadsheet on a web app / Google Site?

Comment: I don't think so.  They also don't work in mobile sheets app.   I'd try a web app. If your users are fairly savvy you can save yourself a lot of work by entering data in one text area separated by delimiters of your choice.

Comment: Also, i don't know how do a Web App.